# How to make app playing audio in the background (phonegap 1.5.0 on iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app to play some music, using PhoneGap and html5 audio tag to play audio on iOS. previously it could play music in the background perfectly (with PhoneGap 1.0.0 for iOS), but after I upgraded PhoneGap to 1.5.0(Cordova), I can't get it play on the background anymore.

When I press HOME button, the audio pauses. When I switch back to app, it resumes.

I have already set the `Required background modes` in the `Info.plist` with value `audio`.

So is there something I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the MainController.h file change the following:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation MainViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm not sure if the following is necessary but I cleaned my project (CMD+ALT+K), recompiled the PhoneGap / Cordova Lib (change target and let it run to simulator) and (after changing the target again) compiled to the application once more and now it works!

**Beware**: it only works on Device, not on the simulator

Comment: This gives an error on AVAudioSession if you don't make sure to add the #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: Sadly also doesn't work on latest version of phonegap

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ayame__'s answer I noticed that the application might be sent from background to suspended mode when you try to skip songs (in a radio or playlist based app).

I wrote a simple plugin that you can find here - https://github.com/vadimf/phonegap-audio-payer