# Playing music while cordova app is in background (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova

I have not found a definite answer to this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833841/how-to-make-app-playing-audio-in-the-background-phonegap-1-5-0-on-ios?s=10%7C0.4676) SO article from 2012 does not work anymore.

So far I have included `audio` in the `UIBackgroundModes` array in my `Info.plist` file.

Furthermore I installed the `cordova-plugin-media` plugin (version 3.0.1). But the music still fades out when I press the home button. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was, that I didn't see an `Info.plist` file and simply created my own.

Under cordova the file is called `<app_name>-Info.plist` and located in the `Resources` folder. Either way it can also be accessed under the `Info` tab when selecting the project target.

So after adding `audio` to `UIBackgroundModes` to the correct file even the simple HTML5 `<audio>` tag continues to play in background. Yay!